# How can we use count function with joins in php laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, join, count, raw

We are working on php laravel project where we find relational data using joins which we get correctly but we also want to find out count of this dafa which we get from joins but when we apply count function with joins then it gives same count value of all data which we get from database using joins.

[image]

this is the code and kindly let me know that what is the issue in this code thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don`t get your question but I think you want count of the retrieve data.
1st method:

```
$variabel = Model::all();
```

View

```
$variabel->count();
```

2nd method:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->count();
```